# Overcoming lack of refs in stateless components

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to create a stateless Search component. When the button is clicked, I need to access the value of the search field. Is the following an acceptable way to do this? Are they any drawbacks to this approach?

```
const Search = ({onBtnClick}) => {
    const onClick = (e) => {
      const query = e.target.previousSibling.value;
      onBtnClick(query);
    };  

    return(
      <div>
        <input type="search" />
        <button onClick={onClick}>Search</button>
      </div>
    )   
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In stateless components you can use `ref` with `function`, like so

```js
const Search = ({ onBtnClick }) => {
  let search;
  
  const setNode = (node) => {
    search = node;
  };
  
  const onClick = () => {
    onBtnClick(search.value);
  };  

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="search" ref={ setNode } />
      <button onClick={ onClick }>Search</button>
    </div>
  );  
}

function onBtnClick(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Search onBtnClick={onBtnClick} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: That's interesting. I suppose an advantage of this approach over mine is that it's not reliant on the `input` being the `previousSibiling` of the `button`, making it a bit more flexible. On the flip side, there's a bit more code, and it's arguably a bit harder to read/follow. Is that fair?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not connoisseur of react, but i think that your approach is OK,
because in official react documentation i saw NOT one time something like that `{value: event.target.value}`:

[image]

Here we have component with state, and have this:

```
this.setState({value: event.target.value});
```

but i think in your component without state it will be OK use:

```
let query = e.target.previousSibling.value;
onBtnClick(query);
```

PS: I also like Alexander T. answer.)